# Access - Filtering Continuous Form Text Field From A ComboBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to filter a Continuous Form by the [Resource Categories] field which is a text box using a combobox [ComboResourceCatV2] And then a second filter to check the operation is still open [OpCmplt]

```
Me.Filter = [Resource Categories] = " & ([ComboResourceCatV2]) & " And ([OpCmplt] = False)
Me.FilterOn = True
```

I don't understand as i have used this approach before  without issue but this time it keeps returning a blank form...

Any suggestions what maybe causing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ty this:

```
Me.Filter = "[Resource Categories] = '" & [ComboResourceCatV2].Value & "' And [OpCmplt] = False"
```

Your quotation marks were a bit off.

Comment: Booooom… that got it working….. I can’t believe I didn’t try .Value       I had the quotation marks pretty much where you have them but took them out as kept getting a pop up asking me for the combo value     Aghhhhh! I can’t believe it was asking me for a value and I didn’t try .Value    Thanks very much… I’ve spent all day trying to get that working

Comment: No bother. Keep in mind to wrap text values in single quotation marks `' '`.